# What's wrong with my <xsl:param>?

Tags: xslt, parameters

I have an `xsl:param` that I'm trying to use to do a template match on an attribute.  By everything I've found here and on the Internet, I'm doing this correctly. However, my output is blank.

Here is my xslt

```
<xsl:param name="strm_name">main</xsl:param>    
<xsl:template match="stream[@name='{$strm_name}']"></xsl:template>
```

If I hardcode the param call to "main", this works just fine.
Here is the XML tag I'm trying to match to..

```
<doc><stream name="main"></stream></doc>
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Would you please share how does your source xml look like? Without it it's pretty hard to figure out what went wrong...

Comment: Is this XSLT 1.0? If so, you can't use a variable reference in a match pattern.

Comment: I've added the source XML tag that I'm trying to match to.

Comment: @lwburk I'm using 1.0, but I can't use a variable in this case. I have to use params due to the environment that I have to use to transform.

Comment: You can't use a param in a match pattern, either. See my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see two issues:

1. You cannot use a variable or parameter reference in a match pattern in XSLT 1.0
2. You do not need the surrounding `'{...}'` when referencing your parameter in the predicate. (You're probably confusing this with an Attribute Value Template.) Use this instead: `stream[@name=$strm_name]`

A possible workaround for issue #1 is to select only those elements that meet the criteria controlled by your param. (You *can* reference a param in a select expression).

For example, this stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="text" />
    <xsl:param name="strm_name" select="'main'"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="/*/stream[@name=$strm_name]" />
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="stream">
        <xsl:apply-templates />
        <xsl:text>/</xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Applied to this document:

```
<root>
    <stream name="main">1</stream>
    <stream name="other">2</stream>
    <stream name="main">3</stream>
    <stream name="main">4</stream>
    <stream name="other">5</stream>
    <stream name="other">6</stream>
</root>
```

...matches only the desired nodes. Output:

```
1/3/4/
```

Comment: This was my problem: stream[@name=$strm_name]. I removed the {'...'} and it is working perfectly! Thank you!!  Hooray for syntax! ;)

Comment: +1 Correct. Enforce the fact that **you can do it in XSLT 2.0**, as per OP's comment...